Prove that $f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{r\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+re^{it})e^{-it}dt$
If $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ is an holomorphic function on the disk $D_R(z_0)$. If $0<r<R$, show that
$$f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{r\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+re^{it})e^{-it}dt$$
My attempt:
$$ f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\alpha} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz $$
where $\alpha(t)=z_0+re^{it}$, $t\in [0,2\pi]$, then by definition of a path integral
$$ f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(\alpha(t))}{(\alpha(t)-z_0)^2}\alpha'(t)dt $$
$$ f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{(re^{it})^2}rie^{it}dt $$
$$ f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0+re^{it})e^{-it}dt $$
then (this is where I get stuck)
$$ f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi} (u(z_0+re^{it})+iv(z_0+re^{it}))e^{-it}dt $$
from what I need to show, I gather that I need to somehow show that
$$ i\int_0^{2\pi} v(z_0+re^{it})e^{-it}dt=\int_0^{2\pi} u(z_0+re^{it})e^{-it}dt $$
My guess is that Cauchy-Riemann equations are needed to show this but I don't know where to start. Thanks in advance, any comment will be appreciated.

Use power series centered at $z_0$ and note that if $f(z)=\sum a_k(z-z_0)^k$ we have $f'(z_0)=a_1$ while $2u(z)=f(z)+\overline{f(z)}$ and integrating against $e^{-it}$ only the coefficient of $z-z_0$ gives a potentially nonzero result by orthogonality and that is exactly $a_1/2$
